# I need to drag and drop some images and need to form a floor plan as html

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, d3.js, html5-canvas, interact.js

I just want to create a floor plan with drag,drop,rotate and delete elements and after that need to save the plan in HTML format. 
My requirement is that we have to create a floor plan, while going the work we have to show status of work to admin.
i.e like bedroom is completed, hall is completed like that with some colours.

Please give your suggestions to achieve the task I am a PHP developer I have knowledge on Javascript, jQuery and HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have achieved this requirement using convas HTML,javascript and jquery. Thanks guys

Comment: @gopinach please could you share your solution because I am looking the for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this requirement using convas HTML,javascript and jquery. loaded below frameworks.
html2canvas.js,Blob.js,canvas-toBlob.js.